# Python3 subprocess: get more than 8-bits of process return code

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess

In the following code:

```
import subprocess

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=False,
                           stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                           stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
process.wait()
out, err = process.communicate()

ret = process.returncode # <--- this returns only 8-bits
```

`process.returncode` returns only the lower 8 bits of the process's return code (as in a shell). I want to access all of the 32-bits returned by the process. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Why do you mean by 8 bits ? Usually the returncode should be 0 to indicate the Subprocess succeeded, other numbers indicate errors.

Comment: Yes, those other number range is what I'm interested in. My application returns more than 255 error codes, which doesn't fit in 8-bits.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/418784/what-is-the-min-and-max-values-of-exit-codes-in-linux

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, thanks, I have seen this pose before asking this question. It didn't help me.

Comment: `... uses the wait(), waitpid(), wait3(), wait4() system calls to retrieve it, only the lower 8 bits of it are available `. Python's subprocess is using `waitpid()' internally you might need to write a wrapper arround [os.exec*()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl)